# Mounting ADLS - Secret does not exist with scope: <scopename> and key: <keynameforservicecredential>

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I try to mount data lake gen2 to Databricks, but failing. I wonder why.
There is Secret called "DataLakeSecret" in the App Registration.
There is Key Vault Secret named "StorageGen2Secret" and it has secret value of DataLakeSecrets.

```
//http://www.stevedem.com/mounting-adls-gen2-in-databricks/
//https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2.html#mount-adls- 
   filesystem&language-scala

//Session configuration
val applicationid = "1111158b9-3525-4c62-8c48-d3d7e2c16a6a"
val secret = "1111xEPjpOIBJtBS-W9B9Zsv7h9IF:qw"
val tenantID = "11114839-0afa-4fae-a34a-326c42112bca"
val scopename = "key-vault-secrets"
val keynameforservicecredential = "StorageGen2Secret"
val fileSystemName = "fileshare1"
val storageaccountname = "111datalake"

val configs = Map(
  "fs.azure.account.auth.type" -> "OAuth",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type" -> 
  "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id" -> "<applicationid>",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret" -> dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "<scopename>", key = " 
  <keynameforservicecredential>"),
        mountPoint = "/mnt/<mount-name>",
      extraConfigs = configs)

//ERROR:
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Secret does not exist with scope: <scopename> and key: 
<keynameforservicecredential>
    at 
com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.SimpleSecretManagerClient.getSecret(SecretManagerClient.scala:228)
at com.databricks.dbutils_v1.impl.SecretUtilsImpl.getBytesInternal(SecretUtilsImpl.scala:46)
at com.databricks.dbutils_v1.impl.SecretUtilsImpl.get(SecretUtilsImpl.scala:61)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may follow the below steps to create mount point using Azure Key-vault.

You should have the following information:

•   Client ID (a.k.a. Application ID) => Key Name as ClientID = 06exxxxxxxxxxd60ef

•   Client Secret (a.k.a. Application Secret) => Key Name as ClientSecret = ArrIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbMt]*

•   Directory ID (a.k.a Tenant ID) => Key Name as  DirectoryID = https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/token

•   Databricks Secret Scope Name => chepra

•   File System Name => filesystem

•   Storage Account Name => chepragen2

•   Mount Name => Kenny

**Azure Data Lake Gen2 mount normal method:**

**Scala Code:**

```
val configs = Map(
  "fs.azure.account.auth.type" -> "OAuth",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type" -> "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id" -> "06ecXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX60ef",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret" -> "ArXXXXXXXXXXXXXMt]*",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint" -> "https://login.microsoftonline.com/72f98XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1db47/oauth2/token")

// Optionally, you can add <directory-name> to the source URI of your mount point.
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "abfss://filesystem@chepragen2.dfs.core.windows.net/",
  mountPoint = "/mnt/Kenny",
  extraConfigs = configs)
```

[image]

**Azure Data Lake Gen2 mount using Azure Key-vault:**

Creating scope using Azure Key Vault:

**Note:** Scope Name is the keyvault name i.e, "chepra" and Key are created as show.

Go to Azure Portal => Select the Key Vault created => create secrets as follows:

- ClientID = 06exxxxxxxxxxd60ef
- ClientSecret = ArrIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbMt]*
- DirectoryID = https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/token

[image]

**Scala Code:**

```
val configs = Map(
            "fs.azure.account.auth.type" -> "OAuth",
            "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type" -> "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
            "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id" -> dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "chepra", key = "ClientID"),
            "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret" -> dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "chepra", key = "ClientSecret"),
            "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint"-> dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "chepra", key = "DirectoryID"))

// Optionally, you can add <directory-name> to the source URI of your mount point.
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "abfss://filesystem@chepragen2.dfs.core.windows.net/",
  mountPoint = "/mnt/Kenny01",
  extraConfigs = configs)
```

[image]